# jQuery: How can I dynamically add a table attribute to a specific cell in a row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that is generated via JavaScript and jQuery. In some of the cells there is a catalog string, `catalogIndex`, that is truncated via CSS. I want to be able to add a title attribute to those specific cells so that users can see the entire string.

I've tried using the `.attr` method in jQuery like this:

`$(queueRow[5]).attr('title', catalogIndex);`

`queueRow` is a variable that holds the actual row for an HTML table. Earlier in the code, I've created it using:

`var queueRow = document.getElementById("copyQueue").insertRow();`

I can insert individual cells like this:

```
    //variable that uses queueRow and creates a new cell.
    var catCell = queueRow.insertCell();

    //add text to the cell using the content of catalogIndex
    catCell.innerHTML = catalogIndex;
```

I attempted to target the appropriate cell (in my case, the 6th position of `queueRow`) and add the title attribute. I don't get any errors, but nothing appears to have been added to that cell. What's the correct syntax to get the position of the cell I want?

Comment: How are you getting the `queueRow` object? Have you tried `console.log(queueRow[5])` to be sure that is the proper DOM object?

Comment: Please add a sample of your table and code.

Comment: Instead of `queueRow[5]` do `queueRow.cells(5)`. But really, as you are using jQuery, why do you use these long `document.getElementById`, ...etc, when there is such snappy jQuery syntax for all that?

Comment: @trincot, I'm getting an error saying that `queueRow.cells` is not a function. Looks like `.cells()` is part of a plugin that I'm not using. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Sorry that should read `queueRow.cells[5]` it is a standard DOM property of a table row element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `cells` property:

```
var queueRow = document.getElementById("copyQueue").insertRow();
// ...
var catCell = queueRow.insertCell();
catCell.textContent = catalogIndex; // don't use innerHTML for pure text.
// ...
$(queueRow.cells[5]).attr('title', catalogIndex);
```

But you should try to use more of jQuery. For instance:

```
var $queueRow = $("<tr>").appendTo("#copyQueue");
// ...
var $catCell = $("<td>").appendTo($queueRow).text(catalogIndex);
// ...
$("td", $queueRow).eq(5).attr('title', catalogIndex);
```

But if you already have `$catCell`, you maybe don't need to find that cell again, and can just do the last two actions in one:

```
$("<td>").appendTo($queueRow).text(catalogIndex).attr("title", catalogIndex);
```

Comment: The other Javascript you saw was legacy code, so no worries - it'll probably be converted soon! Thanks for your help.